# how to get consistent python logging format?

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to set the python logging format, but it seems to ignore my config settings. Is there something to do with hierarchy of loggers that I don't understand?

I have something like

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s')
```

but all the logs still come out with timecode etc.

I read somewhere about how logging format is inherited.

I've tried adding this to many different files in case somehow the `first` encounter with a logging config sets it for the whole session.

The only way I can get this to stick is creating a custom logger in every file, which is tedious with like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('name')
# then configure and use logger.info() etc.
```

Trivial thing, but this has bugged me for a long time! Working on cluttered remote shells where I want to get rid of all the time code guff.

Comment: Are you using django? Try looking at https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-logging-right-way/

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the first logging configuration call sets it for the whole session. That is actually the expected behavior. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html):

> The call to `basicConfig()` should come *before* any calls to `debug()`, `info()` etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration facility, **only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent calls are effectively no-ops**.

Therefore, you should find the first configuration and set your log format there, removing all subsequent configurations.

However, if that is not practicable then there is a workaround available [since Python 3.8](https://bugs.python.org/issue33897)  to force reconfiguring the logging system:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO, force=True)
```

---

*Demo:*

```
import logging 

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
log.info("first")
logging.basicConfig(format='%(message)s', level=logging.INFO, force=True)
log.info("second")
```

*Outputs:*

```
INFO first
second
```

Comment: thanks for this, but `force` doesn't seem to work. how infuriating. literally first line of first file is logging config then a test log.

Comment: @dcsan  force does work, added a demo script.  Can you create a reproducible example where it is not working?

Comment: tx for the comment. it's a bit hard to extract as this is a large multifile project.